# How to apply effect with QGraphicsPixmapItem?

Tags: qt

```
void MainWindow::save()
{
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *gpx = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(_im));
    QGraphicsBlurEffect *effect = new QGraphicsBlurEffect;
    effect->setBlurHints(QGraphicsBlurEffect::QualityHint);
    effect->setBlurRadius(20);
    gpx->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
    _gpx = gpx;
    _image_label->setPixmap(gpx->pixmap());
    _image_label->adjustSize();
    MainWindow::repaint();
}
```

Do not mind the function name, it's just a test button. When I press it, I saw the image in the image label as is, with nothing applied to it. I have low expirience in Qt, so I can't understand what is my problem here and how can I debug it myself.

Comment: Solution: easy way to implement effect - just use it on label.

Comment: Well, this won't work on image...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather of the code you've written, you have a member variable `_gpx` which is a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` that you've already added to your scene.  Every time this function is called you're replacing (and likely leaking memeory) that member variable with a whole new QGraphicsItem which you are **not** adding to the scene.

If your intention is to replace this item then you need to do something like this:

```
scene->removeItem( _gpx );

... // (contents of your save() function )

scene->addItem( _gpx );
```